# Does the API provide controls for remote video playback?

Tags: android, android-cast-api, android-mediasession

I'm aware of `MediaController`, but as I understand, it is only good if you have the video playing in a `VideoView`.
I'm using the LG Connect SDK to play a video on a remote device and I'm able to implement the `MediaController.MediaPlayerControl` interface.

Do I need to design controls for pausing and seeking from scratch?